# Bash get input while flag present?

Tags: bash, shell-script, options, parameter

I'm writing a bash script that has optional flags but also an input.

I can't get the input as `$1` because when flags are present the input is shifted.

So for example if I run `script.sh test` then `$1` will be equal to test.

But if I run `script.sh -b test` then `$1` will be equal to -b.

```
while getopts 'bh' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    b) boxes= 'true' ;;
    h) echo "options:"
       echo "-h, --help                show brief help"
       echo '-b                        add black boxes for monjaro'
       ;;
    *) error "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
  esac
done

echo $1;
```

*The amount of flags I have is not set, I know I will add more in the future.*

How can I consistently get the first non-flag value?

Comment: So, what is your question ?

Comment: @Carpette added to end of question. How can I get first non-flag value, given unknown amount of flags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically use `getopts` as:

```
while getopts...; do
  # process options
  ...
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

printf 'First non-option argument: "%s"\n' "$1"
```

The `shift` above discards all option arguments (including the trailing `--` if any) processed by `getopts`.

Comment: works great thanks, will accept in 10